# Does it differ to use optimizer.step or model.step in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

In pytorch, to update the model, should I use `optimizer.step()` or `model.step()` ?

Here is a example snippet:

```py
import torch
import torch nn
class SomeNeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,hs,es,dropout):
          SomeNeuralNet(ClaimRecognizer, self).__init__()
          # Some initialization here
    def forward(x):
          # forward propagation here

model = SomeNeuralNet(es,hs,dp)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())
loss_function = nn.NLLLoss()
for epoch in N:
   for x in data:
      logp = model(x)
      loss = loss_function(logp,gold_outs)
      loss.backward()
       # Which one I should call ? Optimizer.step() or model.step() or both ?
       optimizer.step()
       model.step()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the gradient descent step, you normally use just `optimizer.step()`. 
Here is also an example taken from the *[documentation (same link at bottom)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#taking-an-optimization-step)*, what it looks like in general:

```py
for input, target in dataset:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(input)
    loss = loss_fn(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

I don't know where you got this `model.step()`? Does did you try it?

If your model really possesses some kind of *`step()`-functionality*, it probably does something different.

But unless you define something extra, your `model` gets its functions from [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module) and this does not have `step` function!

See this example from the the [Pytorch Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module):

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 20, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        return F.relu(self.conv2(x))

model = Model()
model.step()
```

Trying to call `step()` result in an `AttributeError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-b032813f7eda> in <module>
     13 
     14 model = Model()
---> 15 model.step()

~/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    530                 return modules[name]
    531         raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
--> 532             type(self).__name__, name))
    533 
    534     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'step'
```

To sum it up, normally your `model` should *not* have a `step()` function, `optimizer.step()` is the way to go if you want to do the *optimization step*.

See also here:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#taking-an-optimization-step

Answer (score 0):

There no model.step() in pytorch, you may check your code again. I guess you created step function when you were creating Model. If so, you may use model.Module.step() to realize step function.